External hard drive is not recognized in Ubuntu
I have an external hard drive that maybe is broken. If i plug it into the USB port, I can see it with lsusb .
Bus 003 Device 020: ID 13fd:1617 Initio Corporation 

It does not show up in lsblk. I also tried the Disks app, but it also does not show up there either.
sudo dmesg sees that I mounted something:
[524919.681763] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[524919.808113] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=13fd, idProduct=1617, bcdDevice= 1.00
[524919.808115] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0

I tried to mount the drive anyway, since it used to be seen in Windows, as a FAT32 system via:
sudo mkdir /media/usb
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/bus/usb/003/020 /media/usb

but mount says that /dev/bus/usb/003/020 is not a block device. The dmesg output after this command is:
[526911.782407] audit: type=1400 audit(1728727201.966:383): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firmware-updater.firmware-notifier" name="/proc/sys/vm/max_map_count" pid=114237 comm="firmware-notifi" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

Is there anything else I can try? Can someone tell me whether the drive is broken or whether I might salvage it by installing some firmware?
I must say that Windows also does not detect this disk as a hard disk, so maybe it is broken.

/dev/bus/usb/003/020 is not a block device indicates that Ubuntu (and most likely Windows as well) is unable to recognize the USB external hard drive as a proper storage device that can be mounted.

Did it work before? My USB adapter worked with SSD, but not with HDD as USB powered and not enough power. If using HDD, you need external power for adapter. I now prefer SSD for external drives.
